# When I click update project of IDEA, two options pop up. What's the difference between these two options?

Tags: intellij-idea

When I click update project of IDEA, two options pop up. What's the difference between these two options?

1. Merge incoming changes into the current branch
2. Rebase the current branch on top of incoming changes

[image: update project]

[image: two options]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When do you use Git rebase instead of Git merge?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/804115/when-do-you-use-git-rebase-instead-of-git-merge)

Answer (score 1):

When you run `Update project`, essentially, IDE runs a `git fetch`+`git merge` OR `git fetch`+`git rebase`

You can read more about this here:

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/sync-with-a-remote-repository.html#update

As for [Merge](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge) and [Rebase](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase) themselves you can read in official Git documentation